# customize google maps with popups

Tags: java, wordpress

Is there an platform that you know of that I can use google maps and make it completely customized to look like this:
[michigan_map_idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oysb1.jpg)

Also it is important that we would be able to add a hover popup as well as a selection popup from the location dots. I just want to know whether it is possible to do this. The end goal is to upload the map to wordpress. We are open to coding with javascript, html and css.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a plugin, tool, software library, tutorial, book, or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. If you cannot find a resource that does what you want it to, then you'll need to write your own.

Comment: Also this question should not be tagged with `Java`.  It has nothing to do with that language.

Answer (score 0):

This might help in regards to styling your map the way you want: https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/

For the yellow dot as marker, I would make custom markers, more info here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/custom-markers

For hover events you can follow the marker click event guide by google, but instead of click - you guessed it - use hover (if this does not work mouseenter and mouseleave):
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-simple